# Changes made to an entity in MVC are not being commited to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using Repository Pattern and Entity Framework to communicate with my database and Core stuff.

When I try to make a change to a user entity (change email address, username etc), it does not commit this change in the database. I realise I have missed some stuff out of the update method in my repositoy base, the trouble I am having is finding what I have missed out. Any ideas what I am missing? Very new to repository pattern.

I have been following the tutorial - https://workspaces.codeproject.com/user-10620241/architecture-guide-asp-net-mvc-framework-n-tier-en

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        UserModel user = _userService.GetSingle(u => u.Id == id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _userService.Update(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**RepositoryBase.cs**

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T: class
{
    public RepositoryBase()
        : this(new ObRepositoryContext())
    {
    }

    public RepositoryBase(IRepositoryContext repositoryContext)
    {
        repositoryContext = repositoryContext ?? new ObRepositoryContext();
        _objectSet = repositoryContext.GetObjectSet<T>();
    }

    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
    public IObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _objectSet;
        }
    }

    #region IRepository Members

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        this.ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        this._objectSet.Attach(entity);

        //TODO: Commit update to database here
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        this.ObjectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.ToList<T>();
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).ToList<T>();
    }

    public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public long Count()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.LongCount<T>();
    }

    public long Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).LongCount<T>();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: You already have a comment `//TODO: Commit update to database here`

Comment: Yes, I put that there for my reference. Im not sure how to commit this to the database though

Comment: You should call `SaveChanges()` of your context. You can declare this method in interface, or create something like `Commit()` and call `SaveChanges()` in its implementation

Comment: `repositoryContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Though you are not keeping the context anywhere...

Comment: @DavidG thats what I think is the problem. Like mentioned above, I have followed the tutorial and it is not obvious how to call SaveChanges on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you seem to have left yourself a TODO :)

```
 //TODO: Commit update to database here
```

You'll need to flag the object as Modified - here's a take at this:

```
 this.ObjectSet.Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(
     entity, EntityState.Modified);
```

You are also going to want to call [`SaveChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx) at some point on your context - it seems the pattern you have encourages multiple changes and one final commit at some point:

```
repositoryContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit**

The compile error is because the repo you are using has abstracted `ObjectSet` to its interface, `IObjectSet`. You'll need to downcast it again:

```
  _objectSet // Or I guess (this.ObjectSet as ObjectSet<T>)
    .Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
```

Note that the pattern you are following was done in 2010 with EF 4.0. A lot has happened with Entity Framework since then, most notably [`DBContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) which closes much of the gap with the repository pattern, IMO.

Comment: When I put this.ObjectSet.Context, I get an error - Cannot resolve symbol 'Context'.

Comment: I've updated - you'll need a cast or just use the private field directly. You might also look at using `DbContext` instead?